# Replace part of URL using

Tags: c#, url

I have a url that looks like this

`https://domain1.com/go/2345/Default.aspx?c%7c2vCZVIjuUzLTfgsgagasgsgasgsagag`

I would like to be able to replace the domain1.com for domain12.com so it would look like this 
`https://domain12.com/go/2453545/Default.aspx?`

How I can replace only the domain1.com part? Quick note : Everything after the "go/"changes every time I open the browser

I try this

I get the  Url from the browser

```
string getUrl = Url;
```

then I replace the value

```
string newUrl = getUrl .Replace(getUrl .Substring(url.IndexOf(go)
```

Comment: Please don't remove highlighting from your fake "links" because they act as real links

Answer (score 2):

```cs
var u = "https://domain1.com/go/2345/Default.aspx?c%7c2vCZVIjuUzLTfgsgagasgsgasgsagag";
var uri = new Uri(u);
var path = 
    uri.PathAndQuery.Substring(0, uri.PathAndQuery.Length - uri.Query.Length);
string newUrl = "https://domain2.com" + path;
Console.WriteLine(newUrl);
// OUTPUT:  https://domain2.com/go/2345/Default.aspx
```